# How can I stop Mobile Safari clicking links for me after it's brought up the keyboard?

Tags: html, mobile-safari

I have a form which looks like this in my web app

```
--------------
|text input  |
--------------
--------
|Submit|
--------
Link to another page
```

When I click on the text input in Mobile Safari, the keyboard jumps up the screen, with the result that the place where my finger just was is on top of the link to another page. Then the link below the text input triggers.

How do I stop Safari from jumping when I click on the input field?